# On every click link changes in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

This is the blade view to create the url links

```
@section ('category')
    <ul class="main-categories">
        @foreach($category as $category)
            <li class="main-nav-list"><a href="{{asset('/glassfilm')}}/{{$category->category}}">{{ $category->category }}<span class="number">{{ $category->count}}</span></a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

when i click for the first time it's working fine and the url I get is

> http://localhost/shopnew/public/glassfilm/Frosted

when I click for the secon time the url I get is

> http://localhost/shopnew/public/glassfilm/glassfilm/Frosted

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't want to create url's with the `asset()` function. You should use that function only to include stuff like css and javascript files. For url links use the `route()` function.

Comment: Can you show your route

Comment: Route::get('/glassfilm/{name}' , 'GlassFilmController@search_by_category')->name('glassfilm-category');

Comment: @GauravSingh You need to use laravel `route()` method in your view blade file like
`<a href="{{ route('glassfilm-category',  $category->category)}}">{{ $category->category }}<span class="number">{{ $category->count}}</span></a>`

Answer (score 2):

`asset()` method is used to include CSS/JavaScript/images files.

`url()` method used to generate a URL to a link.

Laravel's `route()` method is very helpful. So you can try:

```
<li class="main-nav-list"><a href="{{ route('glassfilm-category', ['name' => $category->category]) }}">{{ $category->category }}<span class="number">{{ $category->count}}</span></a></li>

@section ('category')
    <ul class="main-categories">
         @foreach($category as $category)
             <li class="main-nav-list"><a href="{{ route('glassfilm-category', $category->category) }}">{{ $category->category }}<span class="number">{{ $category->count}}</span></a></li>
         @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your route as below :

```
@section ('category')
  <li class="main-nav-list">
    <a href="{{ route('glassfilm-category',['name' => $category->category]) }}"> {{ $category->category }}
      <span class="number">{{ $category->count}}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
@endsection
```