# My Laravel Links keep breaking Each time I restart my server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

My Laravel links keep breaking each time I restart my local server

So, I am using Laravel 9 and my links keep breaking each time I reload the page or when I restart the server
For example

127.0.0.1:8000/cars/1/edit

will become `127.0.0.1:8000/cars/cars/1/edit` next time I click it.

I have searched for a solution and stumbled upon this [On every click link changes in blade view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58711450/15770919)

But the problem is that the guy that asked the question is using named routes from web.php route

I, on the other hand, am using resource routes ( I do not know what to call them = `Route::resource('/cars', CarsController::class);)`[image: Resouce route]

For that reason, I'm finding it difficult to implement the route() solution proposed as his had a named route name

The href I want to make changes to looks like this. I am using resources routes in web.php

```
<a href="cars/{{ $car['id'] }}/edit">Edit &rarr;</a>
```

[image: Href I want to edit]

Comment: You're using a relative URL, so if you're already on `127.0.0.1:8000/cars/1/edit`, the link will look like `127.0.0.1:8000/cars/1/edit/cars/1/edit` when you click on it. Start the URL with `/` so that the browser knows the link should start from the domain root and not the current URL

Comment: You should laravel route

Comment: In route file, remove slash from that path. Laravel is adding slash per need: 
`Route::resource('cars', CarsController::class);` Could be helpful in such case, not 100 pct sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `route()` helper.
They are named to their corresponding method. since you are using route resource only the seven below will work

```
route('cars.index');
route('cars.create');
route('cars.store');
route('cars.edit');
route('cars.show');
route('cars.update');
route('cars.create');

<a href="{{ route('cars.edit', ['car' => $car['id']]) }}"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<a href='{{ url("cars/".$car['id']."/edit") }}'> edit </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo route('cars', ['id' => $car['id'])?>">Edit</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="{{ url('cars' , [ 'id' => $car->id ]) }}/edit"
```